# Obtain Helmhlotz energy from entropy and quasistatic work function

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a N particle system for which I know the entropy as a function of temperature T and the quasistatic work as a function of V. From this I should compute the

a)Helmholtz free energy 
b)and then out of this the pressure
c)And last the work done under any temperature

The work done under quasistatic expansion from $V_{0}$ to $V$ ($V_{0}<V$) at fixed temperature $T_{0}$:
$$
\Delta W = Nk_{b}T_{0}ln\left( \frac{V}{V_{0}} \right)
$$
And the entropy is given by:

$$
S=Nk_{b}\frac{V_{0}}{V}\left ( \frac{T}{T_{0}} \right )^{a}
$$

with $a=const$,$V_{0}=const$ and $T_{0}=const$ for the entropy equation.

To start with I would use 
$$
S=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}
$$

by integration I obtain:

$$
F(T,V,N)=-\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}}{(a+1)VT_{0}^{a}}T^{a+1}+f(V)
$$

Since I know the work done I can just insert the given work function for f(V)
$$
F(T,V,N)=-\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}}{(a+1)VT_{0}^{a}}T^{a+1}+Nk_{b}T_{0}ln\left( \frac{V}{V_{0}} \right)
$$

The pressure is given by the derivative of F with respect to V

$$
P(V,T,N)=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}=-\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}}{(a+1)V^{2}T_{0}^{a}}-\frac{Nk_{b}T_{0}}{V}
$$

This would result in a negative pressure what does not make any sense but i can't find my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $$
F(T,V,N)=-\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}}{(a+1)VT_{0}^{a}}T^{a+1}+f(V)
$$is correct.  The pressure is given by:
$$P(T,V,N)=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}=-\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}}{(a+1)V^2T_{0}^{a}}T^{a+1}-\frac{df}{dV}$$From the quasistatic work equation at constant temperature $T_0$, we know that:
$$P(T_0,V,N)=\frac{Nk_bT_0}{V}$$Therefore,$$P(T_0,V,N)=\frac{Nk_bT_0}{V}=-\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}T_0}{(a+1)V^2}-\frac{df}{dV}$$
Just integrate this ODE to get f(V)

**ADDENDUM**
From the previous equation, it follows that $$\frac{df}{dV}=-\frac{Nk_bT_0}{V}-\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}T_0}{(a+1)V^2}$$
If I substitute this into the equation for the pressure, I obtain:
$$P(T,V,N)=\frac{Nk_{b}V_{0}T_0}{(a+1)V^2}\left[1-\left(\frac{T}{T_0}\right)^{a+1}\right]+\frac{Nk_bT_0}{V}$$
If I integrate the differential equation for f, I obtain:
$$f=-Nk_bT_0\ln{(V/V_0)}+\frac{Nk_bT_0}{(a+1)}\frac{V_0}{V}$$
So, $$
F(T,V,N)=-Nk_bT_0\ln{(V/V_0)}+\frac{Nk_bT_0}{(a+1)}\frac{V_0}{V}\left[1-\left(\frac{T}{T_0}\right)^{a+1}\right]
$$

Comment: Thank you!! But the sign of the first term for the pressure should be a minus. If I make the derivative of $V^{-1}$ I obtain $-V^{-2}$ therefore the sign of the first term of the pressure would be minus the same as I have written above. Or am I going crazy? ;-)

Comment: And one has to determine the f(V) for the Helmholtz free energy since this is asked. If I determine the pressure like you suggest I would run into the same problem again like it should be solved in this exercise but with an undetermined $\hat{f}(T)$

Comment: Please recheck your algebra.  Also, notice that my final two equations involve the pressure at $T_0$, not at arbitrary T.  And also notice that my final equation is a function only of V, so there is no f(T) required.  I don't feel that you read over what I did carefully enough.  If you would like me to complete the solution, I will do that.  But I'm sure, once you have better digested what I have done, you can easily do that yourself.

Comment: I am very sorry I don't mean to offend you. But I have to do a derivative of the following  form $\frac{\partial- KV^{-1}}{\partial V}=KV^{-2}$ and then I have to take a minus again because I have to take the negative derivative. Like you wrote in your answer. This gives me in total -KV^{-2}. I checked this now on wolfram alpha what gives me the same. I don't get it I am sorry.

Comment: Oops.  You are absolutely right.  My error.  Thanks.  I have made the correction.  But, the rest of what I did is correct.

Comment: Yes but then the pressure is negative and this exercise does not make sense or not. And I also don't understand from a mathematical point of view why we not use the work function W(V) supplied to determine f(V) in the Helmholtz free energy since it is defined as $dF=-SdT+dW=-SdT-pdV$ and we are looking for a function of V. What I don't understand of your approach by integrating the pressure term with respect to V wouldn't this introduce again an unknown integration constant depending on T. Although only $T_{0}$ enters at first.Would this approach resolve the sign problem. I can't solve thisODE

Comment: The equation for the work only applies at T0.  Also, the final differential equation involving df/dV is an ordinary differential equation (not a partial differential equation), so integrating it requires only a constant C, not a function of T.  I will complete the analysis in an ADDENDUM.

Comment: Most important of all, you will see that the results I have presented fully satisfy all the conditions specified in the problem statement.